# Make onclick handler ignore clicks on links

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a custom onclick handler for a block element (set up through jQuery's .click() method). This block element can contain links.

I'm fairly certain this is possible, so, how do I have the handler simply return if it was a link I clicked on (so that the link is visited without running my code)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the event object to see if the target is an anchor tag then return true:

```
$("div").click(function(eventObject){

    if($(eventObject.target).is("a"))
        return true;

    //run your code
});
```

Comment: Because the click target may also be a child (or descendant) of a link, it's safer to call ```.closest("a").length == 0``` rather than ```is("a")```

Answer (score 2):

inside your click event, you can check what the event target tagname is:

```
$("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a") {
    return true; //link clicked
  } else {
    //run your usual div click code here...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Forgot about the event being passed in. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

how about testing if the element is an anchor or not inside the on click function?

```
if(this.tagName() == "a")return true;
```

I didn't test it, check it and reply please

Comment: or this.target or sumthing just a comment if that dont work :D

Answer (score 0):

Checking the `nodeName` of `event.target` doesn't work if your links have descendent elements (e.g. `<span>` or `<img>`).

Instead, try walking up the tree from `event.target` (the deepest element) to `event.currentTarget` (the event the event handler was registered on) and checking whether any of those elements are clickable:

```
$("div").click(function(event) {
    if (clickableBetweenTargetAndCurrentTarget(event))
        return; // This click was probably already handled.
    doSomething();
});

function clickableBetweenTargetAndCurrentTarget(event) {
    for (var el = event.target; el && el != event.currentTarget; el = el.parentNode) {
        if (isClickable(el))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function isClickable(el) {
    // TODO: Customize this as appropriate for your webpage.
    return el.nodeName == 'A' || el.nodeName == 'BUTTON';
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/fojaco/2/

*Note that you'll have to customize isClickable for your particular webpage; it's [hard/impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5632016/691281) to tell whether an element is clickable in the general case.*

An alternative approach would be to make sure that all clickable descendants call `event.preventDefault()`, then your click listener on the div only needs to check `event.defaultPrevented` (IE9+). Or the descendants could call `event.stopPropagation()`, as suggested [on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3864133/691281), but [calling stopPropagation can lead to subtle bugs](http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/).