# javascript: How to check if an element is clickable or not

Tags: javascript, clickable

My naive approach is the following:

```
function isClickable(id){     
     elem = document.getElementById(id);
     if (elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a' || typeof(elem.click) != 'undefined'){
        return true;     
     }else{
        return false;     
     }
}
```

Is there anything better I can do?

Comment: i mean, technically everything is clickable...

Comment: You're right. Would it help if I rephrase to: "if I click on it, will something happen?"

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by determining this?

Comment: Actually Firefox needs a nasty script to make it possible to click some html elements programatically

Comment: My goal is testing - after I do some action, does an element become clickable (stops being clickable)

Comment: Do radiobuttons, checkboxes etc fall under the "clickable" term? I mean, you must better define what you mean by "clickable" or "something happen". So far, you have shown you want to detect hyperlinks and elements that have a `click` event defined. But there are more of them - mousedown, dblclick event, imagemaps etc.

Comment: Also - when using bubbling you can make anything clickable without leaving much of a trace - see jQuery.live()

Comment: Depends - are you in control of adding those events? When replying please use `@namehere` to notify the people e.g. `@Shadow` otherwise we won't see your replies here.

Answer (score 1):

For most elements...

```
if(e.getAttribute('onclick')!=null){

 // clickable

}
```

For anchors...

```
if(e.getAttribute('href')!=null){

 // clickable

}
```

Then you have form buttons which require a little more code, and finally you have click-event bubbling to deal with so a perfect solution covering ALL elements would be a nightmare!

However, if you just want something SIMPLE for containers and anchors only, then we can combine the logic above with a...

```
if((e.getAttribute('onclick')!=null)||(e.getAttribute('href')!=null)){

 // clickable

}
```

For the reverse...

```
if((e.getAttribute('onclick')===null)&&(e.getAttribute('href')===null)){

 // not clickable

}
```

Comment: This works quite well but on top of that I added this check too
if(element.getAttribute('role') === "button")