# Javascript check button is clickable or not

Tags: javascript, events, click

I follow the [javascript: How to check if an element is clickable or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632016/javascript-how-to-check-if-an-element-is-clickable-or-not) and check `document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].getAttribute('onclick')` for the https://matchmaking.grip.events/the8thannualrealestatefamilyofficeandprivatewealthmanagementforumwest/event-login page, where I can click the `Login` button, but JS code return `null`

I am able to see `click` eventlistner in Developer tools in `chrome`.

[image: Event Listener view]

This means, its clickable and when I clock, it load new components.

But javascript code return `null`.

[image: Clicable call]

Is there any other way to know if that element is clickable or not ?

Comment: `onclick` attribute does not means that an element Event is not assigned via JavaScript using i.e: `addEventListener` (which BTW is the preferred way to attach listeners). Yes, the *Event listeners* panel should provide you with all the necessary information.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do/accomplish?

Comment: There is one `div` which has `click` event, I can see that in `Event Listeners` tab, but when I use automation using `selenium + python`, and try to send click event, it's failing by saying that, `div` is not clickable. How can I check `div` is clickable or not ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan is there any other way to check if the `Event Listeners` shows, it has `click` event, we can check by coding ?

Comment: @Nilesh besides `getEventListeners` there's no other simple/native way to crawl functions and code ancestry in search for possible dynamic event delegation - as far as I know. Still not sure what's the exact code that's bugging you. Mind to share?